# Regular expression in c# - uk postcode

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for an answer to my regular expresssion problem in c#.  I'm looking for a match on a specific postcode format and have run into problems.  Here is the regex pattern that I'm checking for:

```
([A-Z]{1})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{1})([A-Z]{2})
```

So, this is looking for a format of a letter, two numbers, one number, two letters.

When I tested this on `RegexPlanet.com` is gave me a match, but when I checked in c# it gave an unusual response. While it worked when putting in the test postcode of `A112BB`, when I entered `A112BBCCCC`, that also brought back a match.  Anyone know why c# has chosen to ignore the last characters after the match has been found?  As I said, entering `A112BBCCCC` into the tester on `RegexPlanet.com` failed and said no match.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last characters have been ignored because there are no markers for start/end string. This is probably what you want:

```
^([A-Z]{1})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{1})([A-Z]{2})$
```

Regex matching is looking for **substrings** that match the pattern. Unless you explicitly mark the start/end of lines, it will match it anywhere in your text.

Actually, I'd write it even simpler:

```
^([A-Z])(\d\d)(\d)([A-Z][A-Z])$
```

or even

```
^[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]{2}$
```

And then just use the `string.Substring()` method to get the parts. That should be faster/simpler, I think (though I suppose it's a matter of preference).

Comment: Thanks vilx - that was it.  Didn't have the start and end markers. Cheers

Answer (score 9):

You might find this useful, its about as specific as it gets for UK postcodes...

```
    static public bool IsPostCode (string postcode)
    {
    return (
        Regex.IsMatch(postcode, "(^[A-PR-UWYZa-pr-uwyz][0-9][ ]*[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}$)") ||
        Regex.IsMatch(postcode, "(^[A-PR-UWYZa-pr-uwyz][0-9][0-9][ ]*[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}$)") ||
        Regex.IsMatch(postcode, "(^[A-PR-UWYZa-pr-uwyz][A-HK-Ya-hk-y][0-9][ ]*[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}$)") ||
        Regex.IsMatch(postcode, "(^[A-PR-UWYZa-pr-uwyz][A-HK-Ya-hk-y][0-9][0-9][ ]*[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}$)") ||
        Regex.IsMatch(postcode, "(^[A-PR-UWYZa-pr-uwyz][0-9][A-HJKS-UWa-hjks-uw][ ]*[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}$)") ||
        Regex.IsMatch(postcode, "(^[A-PR-UWYZa-pr-uwyz][A-HK-Ya-hk-y][0-9][A-Za-z][ ]*[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}$)") ||
        Regex.IsMatch(postcode, "(^[Gg][Ii][Rr][]*0[Aa][Aa]$)")
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

RegexPlanet.com is a Java-centric site, and makes the assumption in its default state that you'll be using a Java regex method which only matches entire strings.

.Net (and most other languages) don't have this as a separate method. In order to match only a specific string and nothing else, you need to add start and end anchors (`^` and `$`) to your regex, so it ends up looking like this `^(......)$`.

By the way, while I'm here, I feel I should point out that your expression for a UK postcode is nowhere near complete. Your current regex won't even match most postal districts (eg `SE1`, `GU57`, `SL0`, etc etc, let alone central London codes like `NW1A`)

Due to the number of possible variations in the format, a complete regex pattern for UK postcodes is a pretty long string. You can find a good example of it on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom

Comment: Hi Spudley - cheers, the markers was the problem.  Fixed now. See my answer to Daniel regarding postcode formats - I'm looking to match specific postcode formats

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is not as accurate as it might be.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom) for more info.

In particular, the "district" can be quite varied, and the final component may not contain the letters CIKMOV.

```
^([A-Z]{1,2})([0-9][0-9A-Z]?) ([0-9])([ABDEFGHJLNPQRSTUWXYZ]{2})$
```

Comment: Yeah - there is a good reason for that.  I'm not actually trying to validate the postcode itself - that is done elsewhere on the site.  The uk postcode can fit into any one of 6 variations (e.g. W1 1AA, WC1A 1AA etc) and I specifically need to find out which variation it fits into.  I'll end up matching the postcode to 6 regular expressions, but the ones I've tried so far in c# are finding matches with the wrong postcodes, even though they work on that test site.